# Vbscript MsgBox newline from batch argument

Tags: batch, vbscript, newlines

test.vbs:

```
wscript.quit MsgBox ("Hello"&vbNewLine&"World",0)
```

works.

prova.bat:

```
WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Hello"&vbNewLine&"World" 0
```

Message.vbs:

```
wscript.quit MsgBox (wscript.arguments(0),wscript.arguments(1))
```

not works (Why?).

prova.bat (without newline)

```
WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Hello World" 0
```

works.

Comment: The command line being passed end up being: 
`WScript  //Nologo Message.vbs "Hello"` due to the "
This can be seen in Process Explorer - http://imgur.com/a/7I7MA

Comment: Great! You were able to post. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want a space in the first argument to be replaced with a newline?

Comment: Any ampersands (&) must be escaped with a caret (^&). I also suggest using `Replace(wscript.arguments(0), "\n", vbNewLine)` in your VBScript and changing your .bat file to something like `WScript //Nologo Message.vbs "Hello\nWorld" 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a VBS script, the ampersand `&` means "concatenate" (join) and `vbNewLine` is a defined constant.

In a batch file, the ampersand means "execute this after the previous command is finished," and `vbNewLine` is undefined.

Context is everything here, and you need to figure out what it is that you are passing, and what the operators and variables in each context mean. One of the comments above offers a viable way to take the input from one context and convert it to the other context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Messaggio
Messaggio = Replace(wscript.arguments(0),"\n",vbNewLine)
wscript.quit MsgBox(Messaggio,wscript.arguments(1))
```

Is perfect for Universal Message Box with batch! ;-)
With return value in %errorlevel% in case of choice.
Thanks at all!